# Google Calendar API - Forbidden - Error with Service Account

Tags: php, api, google-calendar-api, http-status-code-403

I try to use the Google Calendar API by php running server side.

I created a service account and use its credentials (via the json file). I am NOT using G Suite.

Now I am able to list events of my calendar but I get a Forbidden - Error, when I try to create a new event.

I shared my calendar with the service account's email address and gave it admin rights for the calendar. I don't know what I am doing wrong! I just can't get it working. I am also using the scope Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR.

The exception: 403 - Forbidden

I have no idea how to debug this problem and how to proceed further.

Can you help me?

Edit: here is my calling code:

```
putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=../google-service-account.json');

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
$client->setScopes([Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR]);
$client->setRedirectUri('urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob');
$service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);

$event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event([
  'summary' => $name,
  'location' => $location,
  'description' => $desc,
  'start' => [
    'dateTime' => $start,
    'timeZone' => $timezone,
  ],
  'endTimeUnspecified' => true,
]);

$calendar = $service->calendars->get($calendarId);
$settings = $service->settings->listSettings();
$list = $service->acl->listAcl($calendarId);
$event = $service->events->insert($calendarId, $event);
```

The first three service calls (`$calender = ...`, `$settings = ...` and `$list = ...`) work fine and in the acl I can also see that the email address of my service account has all rights (role: owner). But the last line `$event = ...` gives the forbidden error...

Comment: Hi there. Could you post the code that you have so far? It's hard to tell what's wrong without seeing anything.

Comment: Ok, I just edited my questio and added the code there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
'endTimeUnspecified' => true,
```

is causing your problem (its googles fault, but you cant tell them that)

if you change to

```
 'end' => [
'dateTime' => $start2,
'timeZone' => $timezone,
 ],
```

it will work (i know it is not what you want and maybe you can figure out a way to adjust $start2 to give you what you want as an end time but the endTimeUnspecified is what is causing it to say 403 forbidden

Comment: Thanks for your help, this fixed my problem. The question is why is there such an option like 'endTimeUnspecified' in the API if it leads to an error anyway ^^?

Comment: it one of those things that worked on their internal servers but does not work on an external server--i found it purely by accident. i set my end time as start + 20 hrs when i want a full day (i have even set end + days and it works for multi day appointment